# Get the Tag "Name" of an EBS volume with Boto 3 AWS Lambda

Tags: lambda, boto3

I am using the script https://github.com/xombiemp/ec2-take-snapshots-lambda/blob/master/ec2-take-snapshots-lambda.py for AWS lambda.

I would like create snapshot and set tag "Name" with the same tag "Name" of the EBS volume, but in the documentation of boto 3 not find how get tag value of EBS volumes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code shows an example of how to find the `Name` tag associated with a volume in boto3.

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
vol = ec2.Volume(id='vol-1234567890123456')
name = None
for tag in vol.tags:
    if tag['Key'] == 'Name':
        name = tag.get('Value')
```

If the volume has a `Name` tag associated with it, the variable `name` will contain that tag value after the loop.  You can then use that value to create the tag on the snapshot using `create_tags`.

Comment: @garnaat -- It doesn't work for me. I get an error "errorMessage": "'str' object has no attribute 'tags'",

Comment: @garnaat --   for tag in volumeId.tags:
            if tag['Key'] =='Name':
                namet = tag.get('Value')
                print(namet)

Comment: some of my tags come out as None and don't seem to be iterable.